# How to constrain items that it's on top of in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, swift5

How would I use auto-Layout to constrain items that it's sitting on? At the moment auto-layout only gives me the option to constrain it to the safe area:

[image: image1]

As you can see in the picture above, it's constraining to the safe area, not the image view it's sitting on (profile_pic_background). On play all the text fields below the line isn't in the view on my phone/simulator with warning:

```
Main.storyboard 2 views are vertically ambiguous.
```

I have a feeling that constraining to items that it's on top of might not be possible, if so what would be the best way to go around this? Is there a way to make separate view files and then add the view as if you're splitting bits of the profile up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold Control, click on one view and drag to the other. When you let go it will let you constrain by vertical spacing. Even better, use a couple of stack views and you can just drag and drop the views in there.